# How to hide apache server version?

Tags: php, client-server, security

1] When i open any web page & view source it. We have JS & CSS. While click on that i'm able to see each JS & CSS file.

Can we manage it like while on click .js & .css file not open

2] Website hosted on linux server. Through tools hackers are able to view Apache server version. Any way to hide it?

Answer (score 3):

No, JavaScript and CSS files are open to the browser, hence they are opened to the user. You can try to obfocusate them, but that will only stall a determined user.

The server version is shown when an error (404, 500) occurs, you can override that default message with your own pages using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 3):

CSS and JS files will be seen by anyone and everyone . They work on HTTP ;) BTW... what you want to hide is your server-side code, like asp,jsp,php. The source code of those files cannot be seen.

To your second question:
Open your .htaccess and put the following it.

```
ServerSignature Off
```

This way, for any error, it will not show what server or version you are using.

Hope it answers you :)

Comment: You are welcome @AnkitShah ... Consider, clicking on Tick next to my answer (accepting) so that others can see this?

Answer (score 0):

When an user gets programm he gets code which will be executed. On the desktop it may be binary data for example. In web development there is no binary data, browser gets code, so user does. You may only obfocusate it.